# creditor not rendering correct in google chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Ckeditor is not rendering correct in google chrome, but it do render it correct in safari and firefox.
This is how it renders in safari and should render https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wV8F.png

This is how it renders in google chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgszI.png

I have deleted all cookies and similar in chrome.

Am using the creditor gem for rails, that is using version 4.4.7 of creditor.

Comment: Have you tried using the non-gem version?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed when i restarted my computer. I had tried resetting all chrome settings before that and it was not working.